# Variant object return from C#.Net dll to Php array

Tags: php, .net, dll

I'm using COM to access .Net Dll files. One thing I wanted is to return an array of string from .Net to Php but its returning a variant object instead.

The C# class library to work I have this parameters.
1 Strong name key. Run VS as administrator to avoid error creating snk file.
2 COM visible
3 Compiled in .Net2.0 to .Net3.5
4 Using VS Dev command regsvr  /codebase

```
namespace CS2Php
{
    public class Arrays
    {

        public string Hello(string s)
        {
            return string.Format("Hello {0} from Arrays", s);

        }


        public string[] StrArray()
        {
            string[] arrNames = new string[3];
            arrNames[0] = "James";
            arrNames[1] = "Smith";
            arrNames[2] = "Hyan";
            return arrNames;
        }
    }

}




<?php
    $objCS2Php = new com('CS2Php.Arrays');

    $a=array();
    $a=(array)$objCS2Php->StrArray();

    print_r($a); // return : variant object
    var_dump($a); // return : object(variant)#2 (0) { }

    // the foreach loop were able to return the correct values
    foreach($a as $array){ 
     echo "Value ".$array. "<br/>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: some kind of typecasting is needed, or a link to known php variable types

Comment: Agree it might work `$a=(array)$objCS2Php->StrArray();`but it did not.

Comment: How does the actual variant object look like? Can you provide us with some output in your question please?

Comment: Logically I'm taking it the return type from .net is an array and by understanding Php has an array type then the two platform will be compatible. The Php print_r return an error message `variant object` and likewise the var_dump return an error message `object(variant)#2 (0) {}`. Basically I did not see the array data James, Smith and Hyan return from .net StrArray() function.

Comment: does the [documentation for variant](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.variant.php) help? For example try using `echo variant_get_type($a);` or `com_print_typeinfo($a);`

Comment: It did eliminate the variant error and return `16396`. This is not inline with the suppose output.

However, the Hello() `echo $objCS2Php->Hello('John Smith');` works perfectly

Comment: use `com_print_typeinfo($a);` to get info about the exact type of variant returned. Some manipulation is needed most probably to get the wrapped result inside php

Comment: Page was unreachable with `com_print_typeinfo($a);` but with `foreach($a as $array)` it able to return the correct values, exactly what I needed.